# telerik RadGantt Binding from Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I want to bind Rad Gantt of Telerik from code behind here is my code:

```
 <telerik:RadGantt runat="server" ID="RadGantt1" Width="1275px" Height="600px" ListWidth="351px"
             SelectedView="WeekView" Skin="Silk" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GanttBoundColumn DataField="TaskName" DataType="String" Width="120px"></telerik:GanttBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GanttBoundColumn DataField="StartDate" DataType="DateTime" DataFormatString="dd/MM/yy" Width="40px"></telerik:GanttBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GanttBoundColumn DataField="EndDate" DataType="DateTime" DataFormatString="dd/MM/yy" Width="40px"></telerik:GanttBoundColumn>
            </Columns>    
               <DataBindings>
            <TasksDataBindings IdField="TaskID" ParentIdField="TaskID" StartField="StartDate" OrderIdField="TaskID" SummaryField="Summary" ExpandedField="Expanded" EndField="EndDate" TitleField="TaskName"
                PercentCompleteField="PercentComplete" />
            <DependenciesDataBindings TypeField="Type" IdField="TaskID" PredecessorIdField="TaskID" SuccessorIdField="TaskID" />
        </DataBindings>    
            </telerik:RadGantt>
```

and in code behind

```
RadGantt1.DataSource = Gatdata();
        RadGantt1.DataBind();
```

I am having this error on `DataBind()` "`DataSourceID` may not be null in case of DataSource binding" here GetData() method return very simple datatable which contains columns and valid data

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try the latest internal build Telerik offer. After re-reading the post it seems I have misunderstood the original issue. This seems like a bug or limitation, so it may already be fixed/improved.

Comment: dude I am receiving error on this line RadGantt1.DataSource = Gatdata(); so how could I data bind it on every postback page does not open throws error

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry for misunderstanding it the first time. Give the LIB a try and if it does not help, reach out to their support :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="QsfScriptManager" runat="server"/>
     <telerik:RadGantt ID="RadGantt1" runat="server"  ReadOnly="false" SelectedView="WeekView" Width="100%" ListWidth="351px"
         Skin="Silk">
        <DataBindings>
            <TasksDataBindings IdField="ID"  ParentIdField="ParentID" StartField="Start" OrderIdField="OrderID" SummaryField="Summary" ExpandedField="Expanded" EndField="End" TitleField="Title"
                PercentCompleteField="PercentComplete" />
            <DependenciesDataBindings TypeField="Type" IdField="ID" PredecessorIdField="PredecessorID"   SuccessorIdField="SuccessorID" />
        </DataBindings>
    </telerik:RadGantt>
```

cs.file

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TelerikConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString());

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM GanttTasks", conn);
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TelerikConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM GanttTasks";
    SqlDataSource2.DataBind();

    SqlDataSource4.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TelerikConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    SqlDataSource4.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM GanttDependencies";
    SqlDataSource4.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE GanttDependencies SET PredecessorID = @PredecessorID, SuccessorID = @SuccessorID, Type = @Type WHERE ID = @ID";
    SqlDataSource4.DataBind();


    RadGantt1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource2.ID;
    RadGantt1.DependenciesDataSourceID = SqlDataSource4.ID;

    conn.Close();
```